# Installation of new OS blocked on laptop

Tags: hard-drive, boot, operating-systems, bootable-media

I own this laptop, which I got from a friend, who got it from some corporation who didn't want it back after quite a while ... point is: I can't ask anybody who might know what is going on with this computer.

It's a X220i, a model I quite like. I'd like to install a new OS since the current is an outdated Windows version. But the installation seems to be blocked. I tried to install Debian from a USB stick that works on other computers, but on this one I can't even choose it in the BIOS startup menu. It resets automatically to the startup menu, and will only boot from the larger SSD. The BIOS is not password protected.

There is an internal SSD 128GB in the laptop, directly attached to the main board, and another, larger, SSD that can be removed much easier, as is common with the X220 series. If I remove the larger SSD and boot, it will attempt to repair Windows, but fail of course. If I remove the internal SSD, it won't even boot from the larger SSD.

What bothers me even more, I put one of my own SSDs in the standard slot (not the internal connector), on which a working Debian distro for X220 was already installed. In the past, switching hard disks like that usually worked. It did not boot, however, instead tried to "repair Windows", and now the disk won't even boot in other computers. It's also an SSD, so I highly doubt it broke for a mechanical reason.

Any ideas? I would really like to install Debian on this computer.

**EDIT**

You are indeed right, it is UEFI. Thanks for pointing that out. I created a USB Stick with Debian 11 Live on it. This stick is working well on other computers. On the laptop though, the system halts during startup at whatever time I plug in the USB stick. I read online updating UEFI might help, which I did; didn't solve the problem. If it's of any interest, it is now version 1.46 (8DET76WW).

I can change everything in the UEFI setup, so I'm positive there is no password. I also reset UEFI options to default. I'm beginning to think this might be rather for security and not to generally prevent installion of another OS, but how to change it?

The other disk's bootloader seems to be damaged by inserting it into the laptop, which explains that at least.

Comment: If the "BIOS" (actually UEFI) isn't password protect you can make changes and certainly boot live/installation media. If it doesn't boot when selected in UEFI > Boot or the one-time boot menu / boot override menu then there's something wrong with the media itself. It seems, from your prose, you aren't really familiar with the UEFI boot mode, its requirements and/or how to manage it.

Comment: on this one I can't even choose it in the BIOS startup menu. It resets automatically to the startup menu, and will only boot from the larger SSD. The BIOS is not password protected.   ......   Are you sure there is not a Supervisor Password?  That is a very old laptop. There are no other blockages as far as I recall.

Comment: @John Thanks for pointing out the age. I assumed it was UEFI but given the age it can be BIOS indeed (Windows attempting a repair suggests UEFI though). If UEFI it's one of the early (and dreadful) implementations and it may present additional challenges.

Comment: *I put one of my own SSDs (...) on which a working Debian distro for X220 was already installed. (...) It did not boot, however, instead tried to "repair Windows"* This is what suggests UEFI but it remains to be confirmed. Can you please open the firmware settings, find a Boot menu and check what options you have there?

Comment: We had X220 at customers and I don't think they had UEFI BIOS. I cannot recall for sure. I have an X230 (later) and it went to UEFI in 2015.

Comment: Regadless of the firmware it should boot external media if properly made and compatible. In this case, assuming @John is correct, media made for UEFI only wouldn't boot indeed.

Comment: " If I remove the larger SSD and boot, it will attempt to repair Windows, but fail of course." - This suggests the boot partition is on another disk other than the SSD. Without a partition map of the disk(s) it's difficut to provide any helpful suggestions.

Comment: I would like to provide a partition map of the disks, however can only identify that the system actually load from the smaller 128GB disk (I assume this because it is mounted as C:\\) and the other disk is for additional storage.